# How do I set suhosin.request.max_* with .htaccess? Only suhosin.post.max_* work

Tags: .htaccess, suhosin

I've set suhosin.perdir = 'p' in my ini file. I would now like to change suhosin ini settings on a per-folder basis.

The following all work (running phpinfo() inside the desired folder shows the changed values):

```
php_value suhosin.post.max_array_depth 100
php_value suhosin.post.max_array_index_length 128
php_value suhosin.post.max_name_length 128
php_value suhosin.post.max_value_length 2000000
php_value suhosin.post.max_totalname_length 512
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
```

But when I also add the .request settings (which I understand are an upper limit for the .post settings), they do not change:

```
php_value suhosin.request.max_array_depth 100
php_value suhosin.request.max_array_index_length 128
php_value suhosin.request.max_name_length 128
php_value suhosin.request.max_value_length  2000000
php_value suhosin.request.max_totalname_length 512
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
```

[image: screenshot for phpinfo]

Do you have any idea if there is anything else I have to check/setup? Am I forgetting someting?

Thank you!
Matei

Comment: I've just checked my own configuration and I don't think you're forgetting anything (yes, you need to up both the limits for post and request). Just an idea, try to change the order in which you write the settings on the .htaccess file to see if it stops processing the .htaccess file after a specific line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I moved all the .request settings above the .post ones. The "post" get updated, the "request" don't.

I also have some rewrite rules below and all work fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to think in another possible solution.

Comment: I've just tried your exact same configuration in my dev machine, and while it accepts changes on .post, there's no way to change the .request. Very strange! I'm on Debian 6. You?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found the solution. I was going to download the Suhosin code to take a look when I found this [post](http://www.mattzuba.com/2011/04/suhosins-suhosin-perdir-directive/), explaining that the perdir "p" directive only affects to the post variables:

```
/* no deactivation so check the flags */
while (*tmp) {
    switch (*tmp) {
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            SUHOSIN_G(log_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            SUHOSIN_G(exec_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            SUHOSIN_G(get_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            SUHOSIN_G(cookie_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
        case 'P':
            SUHOSIN_G(post_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            SUHOSIN_G(request_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            SUHOSIN_G(sql_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            SUHOSIN_G(upload_perdir) = 1;
            break;
        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            SUHOSIN_G(misc_perdir) = 1;
            break;
    }
    tmp++;
}
```

If you want perdir options both per post and request, you need to edit your *php.ini*

```
suhosin.perdir=pr
```

or *.htaccess*

```
php_value suhosin.perdir pr
```

so the value for *perdir* is **pr**

Comment: Looks great. Let me test that out and I'll accept the answer. Thanks!